# Match group followed by group with different ending

Tags: regex

For example, let's say I have a list of words:

#### `words.txt`

```
accountable
accountant
accountants
accounted
```

I want to match `"accountant\naccountants"`

I've tried `/(\n\w+){2}s/`, but `\w+` seems to be perfectly matching different things.

My RegEx also matches the following undesirable texts:

```
action
actionables
```

```
actionable
actions
```

Am I reaching out too far in what regex can do?

Comment: do you maybe mean `(\n\w+)\1s` this says match something, then reference that exact match followed by an s. what you have is match that previous token twice which is not the same thing

Comment: If the strings were `"account"`, `"accountant"` and `"accountants"`, what would be your desired return value?

Comment: You need to state (in words) the *rule* for determining what is to be returned. Examples are fine for illustration but questions generally cannot be stated unambiguously when cast in terms of a single example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example use a capture group, and match a newline followed by a backreference to the same captured text and an `s` char.

If the first word can also be at the start of the string, instead of being preceded by a newline, you can use an anchor `^` instead.

```
^(\w+)\n\1s$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\w+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ word chars
- `\n\1s` Match a newline, backreference `\1` to match the same text as group 1 and an `s` char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ewjOWH/1)